# Vagrant Workflow - vagrant ssh, vagrant destroy, vagrant up commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant

I am having some trouble understanding the vagrant workflow from their website.

I had previously been working on a project and had gone through the whole process of changing directory and setting up the vagrant box, etc. I had even run bundle install that installed all of the gems of the forked project I am working on. I configured the web server to work and was even able to go to see the project on my browser through the web server connection.

Later on I had to go get dinner so I did

```
vagrant destroy
```

When I returned, in the same directory I ran

```
vagrant up
```

Then I did

```
vagrant ssh
```

followed by

```
cd /vagrant
```

when I get here I run

```
rails s
```

and I get the following error:

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Shouldn't running vagrant up remember all of the work I had previously done? Or do I have to restart from scratch and rebuild all of my gems every time? Am I missing something?

Comment: You `vagrant destroy` your previous work, so you start from scratch again. Next time just `vagrant halt` when you want to stop the VM.

Answer (score 5):

`vagrant destroy` does literally what the command says - destroys started up VM, completely with disc images. Every change (i.e. installation of software, results of running `bundle install`, etc) is lost, beyond the changes that happened in `/vagrant` directory.

If you want to just stop the VM without destroying disc images - you should use `vagrant halt` instead (or just power off VM as you would do with a real server - i.e. by issuing `poweroff`).

The general workflow for deploying a vagrant-powered VM outlined in documentation is that you distribute `Vagrantfile` along with your sources that includes provisioning section (`config.vm.provision`) which does the stuff you've described - installation of additional software not bundled in a box image (i.e. Rails, gems), setting up the databases, etc. It can be implemented in several ways, starting from just running a simple shell script (with sequential commands to execute), up to using  high-profile configuration management systems like [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com/), [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/), etc.

Temporary break (like going for dinner) generally does not require even halting a VM, less destroying it. Even a full-fledged VM running under VirtualBox / VMware / KVM with a single-user Rails application hardly consumes lots of resources to worry about.

Comment: I'd go one step farther than @GreyCat and say that doing your setup via provisioners isn't just the "general workflow" but in fact the _whole point_ of Vagrant. :) Your goal should be that you can go from a clean machine to fully-configured dev environment just by doing `git clone your_repo && vagrant up && vagrant ssh`.

Comment: You will cry when your vm gets corrupted, destroyed or lost. This is the whole point: Your goal should be that you can go from a clean machine to fully-configured dev environment just by vagrant up.